# Theming blocks individually, by region, or by module

Tags: 8, theming

I want to create a bock template for a certain region & a certain module. Drupal 8 does not offer these hook suggestions. In Drupal 7 it was [easy to do](https://www.drupal.org/node/104319).

I want to create `block--[region]--[module].html.twig`. How can I add this theme suggestion?